# dplyr::mutate_all calling function with empty parenthesis

Tags: r, dplyr

This might be a known behaviour, but I find it odd - is there a reason why calling a function in mutate_all with empty parenthesis just gives no result (no mutation), without error or warning?

```r
library(tidyverse)
sample_df <- data_frame(id = 1:3, name = letters[1:3])

# with parenthesis
sample_df %>% mutate_all(as.character()) %>% str

#> Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':    3 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ id  : int  1 2 3
#>  $ name: chr  "a" "b" "c"

# without parenthesis
sample_df %>% mutate_all(as.character) %>% str

#> Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':    3 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ id  : chr  "1" "2" "3"
#>  $ name: chr  "a" "b" "c"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood, this is due to `dplyr`'s non-standard evaluation (NSE). From the `?mutate_all` documentation (bold-face mine)

> .funs: List of function calls generated by ‘funs()’, **or a character
>            vector of function names**, or simply a function.

So `dplyr`s NSE means that we can either write

```
sample_df %>% mutate_all("as.character")
```

or

```
sample_df %>% mutate_all(as.character)
```

In other words, we can supply the function name as either a symbol or a character vector.

---

On the other hand, notice how `as.character()` returns

```
character(0)
```

so

```
sample_df %>% mutate_all(as.character())
```

would correspond to passing an empty function name.

Comment: Thanks. Very interesting and makes totally sense